# Use SpeechRecognizer with Bluetooth Headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, speech-recognition, headset

I am using a `SpeechRecognizer` in my app, so I don't have that annoying Speech Input popup.

However, if I try to use this Class when a Bluetooth Headset is connected (via `AudioManager.startBluetoothSco`), it gives me an `ERROR_AUDIO` right after initializing.

Is there a way of getting around this issue? This is acutally really bad, as most of my users use the app with a BT headset....

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any way to prevent this, but you can catch it in onError method of the RecognitionListener.  Just look for SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO and startListening() again.

Answer (score 0):

you may need these if you don't already:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```